# C# extension method, get rid of ref keyword

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I have written a little extension method to add a value to the beginning of a List.

Here is the code;

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static void AddBeginning<T>(this List<T> item, T itemValue, ref List<T> currentList)
    {
        List<T> tempList = new List<T> {itemValue};
        tempList.AddRange(currentList);
        currentList = tempList;
    }
}
```

So that I can add the value to the beginning of the list, I have to use the `ref` keyword.

Can anybody suggest have to amend this extension method to get rid of the ref keyword?

Comment: The angle brackets are shown literally within code blocks, `<like this>` so you can just add them in as usual.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just call `currentList.Insert(0, itemValue);` to insert into the beginning.

**Edit:**

Note - this code will modify the list instance whereas the original code left the list intact and produced a new list with the additional data inserted at the beginning.

Comment: thanks...i have marked your answer as accepted because I now realise that an extension method is unnecessary

Comment: `oldList = currentList; currentList.AddBeginning(newItem, ref currentList);` would leave `oldList` unaffected.  Your suggested replacement would modify the list identified by `oldList`.  Perhaps there was no real need to leave the old list alone, in which case your approach would be fine, but the OP's code would be usable in cases where yours would not.

Comment: @supercat Good point, I should have mentioned the change in semantics. However, given that leaving the original list unchanged was not listed as a requirement, I did not think it would be an issue.

Comment: Yours is not the only answer which changes the list; other people probably also thought it was okay.  Since .NET makes no declarative distinction between references identifying possibly-shared and definitely-unshared objects (a major weakness, IMHO) I tend to assume that code which effectively makes defensive copies is doing so because the objects in question might potentially be shared.

Comment: @supercat I have updated the answer to make the semantics change clear

Answer (score 4):

```
public static void AddBeginning<T>(this List<T> currentList, T itemValue)
{
    currentList.Insert(0, itemValue);
}
```

It *really* helps to read the docs for the class you're using.

Also, I would suggest just using `Insert` directly, instead of this extension method.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [List Insert method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx) and supply the index that you want the new value (0) added at?